# How to prove image equality for functions: x = y -> f x = f y in Coq?

Tags: equality, coq

Intuitively, I know that if `x = y` then `f x = f y`, for any function `f`. But I don't know how to prove this in Coq. What I have so far is:

```
Theorem eq_img: forall {X:Type} (f: X->X) (x y :X), x = y -> f x = f y.
Proof.  intros X f x y eq1.
```

and the state is:

```
1 subgoals
X : Type
f : X -> X
x : X
y : X
eq1 : x = y
______________________________________(1/1)
f x = f y
```

Any pointers on how should I proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Just needed to use `rewrite` to eliminate `x` or `y`, then it's reflexivity.

```
Theorem eq_img: forall {X:Type} (f: X->X) (x y :X), x = y -> f x = f y.
Proof.  intros X f x y eq1. rewrite <- eq1. reflexivity. Qed.
```

Comment: Or you can use the tactics `congruence` (which discards the goal) or `f_equal` (which peels off the `f`).

Comment: You can use `subst` to replace all occurrences of `x` with `y`.

Comment: Thanks people. I'll look into these.